# Harmonic functions proof explanation

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, harmonic-functions

I need help understanding a step in a proof.

Theorem: The imaginary and real part of a regular function on $G$ are harmonic functions on $G$
Proof: Let $f(z) = u + iv$ for $u = u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x,y)$ be regular functions on G. Then we have:
$$f'(z) = \frac{\delta u}{\delta x} + i \frac{\delta v}{\delta y} = \frac{\delta v}{\delta y} \color{red}{ - i \frac{\delta u}{\delta y}}$$
$$f''(z) = \frac{\delta^2 u}{ \delta x^2}  + i \frac{\delta^2 v}{\delta y^2} = -\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta y^2} \color{red}{- i \frac{\delta^2v}{\delta y^2}}...$$
I do not understand where the red terms come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in the first equality of your formula.
$$f'(z)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(z+t)-f(z)}{t}$$

Chosing $t \in \mathbb R$ gives 
$$f'(z)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{u(x+t,y)+iv(x+t,y)}{t}=\frac{\delta u}{\delta x} + i \frac{\delta v}{{ \delta \color{red} x}}$$

Now, C-R gives the first equality.

Now derivating one more time, you should get 
$$f''(z) = \frac{\delta^2 u}{ \delta x^2}  + i \frac{\delta^2 v}{\delta \color{red} x^2}$$

Comment: Is the second equality then incorrect? I mean $-\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta y^2} - i \frac{\delta^2v}{\delta y^2}$

Comment: @user1949350 $$\frac{\delta v}{{ \delta  x}} =- \frac{\delta u}{{ \delta y}} \\\frac{\delta^2 v}{\delta  x^2}= - \frac{\delta}{\delta x}\frac{\delta u}{{ \delta y}} =-\frac{\delta}{\delta y}\frac{\delta u}{{ \delta x}}=-\frac{\delta}{\delta y}\frac{\delta v}{{ \delta y}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Those are called the C-R equations.A complex fuction is diffrentiable only if it satisfies u<sub>x</sub>=v<sub>y</sub> and u<sub>y</sub>=-v<sub>x</sub>.You can see the proofs here.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html